# How to get parameter from lightning URL in Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

How to get parameter from lightning URL in Salesforce? Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

markup required to add the force:hasRecordId interface to a Lightning component.

you can get the id use this interface .

This link should provide more info:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm

Rest of the parameters can be fetched using below javascript:

Link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in `javascript`, like below code:

```
window.location.href
```

The entire URL of the current lightning page will be returned. You just have to `substring` the parameters from the entire link.